# C#. Checkboxes become unchecked

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, registry

I have a problem, that I can't solve.
I am writing an application that will help to change system proxy easily. It has a listView with some items. These items have checkboxes.
Logic of application demands that only one item can be checked at a time, so I have following code to make sure it works well:

```
    private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.ItemChecked -= listView1_ItemChecked;
        foreach(ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            if(item != e.Item)
            {
                item.Checked = false;
            }
        }
        listView1.ItemChecked += listView1_ItemChecked;
    }
```

Also my application needs to check some value in registry on it's start and compare it's text with my items in listView.
I am doing it like that:

```
    private void GetProxyFromRegistry()
    {
        RegistryKey SystemProxy = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings");
        try
        {
            string UsedProxy = SystemProxy.GetValue("ProxyServer").ToString();
            foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
            {
                if (UsedProxy == item.Text + ":" + item.SubItems[1].Text)
                {
                    item.Checked = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Checked = false;
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that none of the listView1.Items will be checked except **last** one when used.
I know that it's because of listView1_ItemChecked(), but I do not know how to solve it the other way.
Can you help me find a solution how to either uncheck all other checkboxes, or find a workaround to make correct item be checked?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense.  You already know how to unsubscribe the ItemChecked event so that could work in GetProxyFromRegistry as well.  But create a more intuitive user interface first.

Comment: User interface couldn't be more intuitive. I do not know how to unsubscribe this event for particular moment (method). Could you please, give me an example?

Comment: It's in your own code!  First line of your ItemChecked event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So starting with your ItemCheck event, it should be like this:

```
void listView1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.currentValue == CheckState.Checked)
            return;
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            if (item.Index != e.Index)
            {
                item.Checked = false;
            }
        }
}
```

For the next issue, I'd suggest setting a breakpoint at this line of code here:

```
   if (UsedProxy == item.Text + ":" + item.SubItems[1].Text)
```

When the breakpoint is hit (on the last index), check to see what's different about that item in comparison to the others (look at case sensitivity, for instance).

Comment: Bad advice.  It also runs when the code sets the Checked property.

Comment: @HansPassant apparently I was wrong!  I've reflected that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this may be a bit of a simple solution to only have one checkbox used at a time, but it works for me. create a listview.click event and then do the following:

```
    private void listView_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
        {
            item.Checked = false;
        }

    }
```

Bit of a hack really, but works great.

Comment: Sorry, amendment to this; i also have a listview.lostfocus method where i then grab my checked value to a variable.